# How to set input style to look exactly the same as tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on React application where you can edit things inline. I'm switching from some tag (`h1`-`h6` or `p`) to `input` when the sentence is clicked *(no, contenteditable didn't work out)*

Is there an easy way I could make the switch seamless? That is, to make the style of text inside an input exactly the same as the html tag counterpart?

I tried `normalize.css` with no luck, I can still see the switch change styles. Is there a better alternative?

Currently I have this CSS (I am still trying out the reset stylesheets):

```css
.tag {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 10px;
}

.heading {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
}

.h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
}

.h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.h5 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.h6 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.p {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.left {
    text-align: left;
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="h1 heading tag">Heading text</h1>
<input class="h1 heading tag" value="Heading text"/>

<p class="p tag">Paragraph text</p>
<input class="p tag" value="Paragraph text"/>
```

Comment: As long as the textual tag and the `input` have the same properties: `padding`, `border`, `font-size`, `line-height` it should work.  Please post an example of what you tried.

Comment: @TigranPetrossian are these all?

Comment: Done it, also using some form reset. The result - when clicked in Chrome it increases a little, while in firefox - decreases.

Comment: is it really that hard to make a working SO snippet or a JSFiddle instead of trying to describe the behavior?

Comment: @TigranPetrossian there you go, same html, looks different. Upvote the question if possible, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using custom styles inside `span`/`div` instead of `h1`. It is a bit of extra work but makes it easier to achieve the same style because you're in total control of all applied style properties, where with the `h1` tag, the browser already applies some styles so you have to match all of those in the input component, not to mention there can be some cross-browser issues.